# How Spring Data JPA implements paging with oracle database since oracle doesn't provides "limit" and "offset" function like MySQL?

Tags: oracle, spring-data-jpa

Spring Data JPA provides Pageable and Sorting funcions. For other DBMS like MySQL, there are "limit" and "offset" functions with themselves to provide the SQL level pagination for Spring. I'm wondering how Spring Data JPA handling Paging with Oracle database as Oracle doesn't have the same functions.
Please kindly let me know where could I find such implementation in Spring's source code.  And will the implementation has performance issue?

Comment: it seems that SDJ uses ROWNUM / ROW_NUMBER(), see http://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pagination/#comment-7469

Comment: What is your database version? If I am not mistaken, 12c does have the features such as limit and offset.

Comment: @user75ponic I think what I stated was oracle doesn't support "limit" and "offset". Do you have any idea on the question?

Comment: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/0a2a5c622e3eb30724e80bc8661c0ac55ebfb2be/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/OracleDialect.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Hibernate's Github repo, [OracleDialect.java](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/0a2a5c622e3eb30724e80bc8661c0ac55ebfb2be/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/OracleDialect.java):

```
@Override
public String getLimitString(String sql, boolean hasOffset) {

    sql = sql.trim();
    boolean isForUpdate = false;
    if ( sql.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).endsWith( " for update" ) ) {
        sql = sql.substring( 0, sql.length()-11 );
        isForUpdate = true;
    }

    final StringBuilder pagingSelect = new StringBuilder( sql.length()+100 );
    if (hasOffset) {
        pagingSelect.append( "select * from ( select row_.*, rownum rownum_ from ( " );
    }
    else {
        pagingSelect.append( "select * from ( " );
    }
    pagingSelect.append( sql );
    if (hasOffset) {
        pagingSelect.append( " ) row_ ) where rownum_ <= ? and rownum_ > ?" );
    }
    else {
        pagingSelect.append( " ) where rownum <= ?" );
    }

    if ( isForUpdate ) {
        pagingSelect.append( " for update" );
    }

    return pagingSelect.toString();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Brian, it's very helpful. Could you share how do you find this as well? After checking the method hibernate handles oracle's pagination, I think there might be performance issue for a large data set, isn't it?

Comment: linc01n the goald of a orm is not really to deal with a huge datraset